# Magento 1.8.1.0 Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Shoppersettings_Helper_Image' not found in

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I’ve installed an extension, and after installing it started giving me this error:

```
Fatal error: Class ‘Mage_Shoppersettings_Helper_Image’ not found in /home/default/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

Even after disabling the extension the error remains. I tried to see if the was something I changed in the Mage.php, but my file is still the same the the default file.

Does anyone know what can be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

helper class is not define properly  in config.xml of that modules

put the below code this

```
<global>
......
<helpers>
            <custommodule>
                <class>Amit_Custommodule_Helper</class>
            </custommodule>
        </helpers>
...
</global>
```

Your code should have

```
<global>
    ......
    <helpers>
                <shoppersettings>
                    <class>YourModulenamaSpace_Shoppersettings_Helper</class>
                </shoppersettings>
            </helpers>
    ...
    </global>
```